# How do I mix let and var in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using a for loop where one of the variables has to survive past the loop. Is it possible to use let in this circumstance - it appears not to work.

```
for (var data=[],let i=0; i<1000; ++i) {
    // Do something here that populates the data variable.
}
```

Or should I just initialise the data variable outside of the loop like this:

```
var data = [];
for (let i=0; i<1000; ++i) {
    // Do something here that populates the data variable.
}
```

Comment: Yes, you *definitely* should declare it outside, if alone to make it clear that is *supposed* to survive the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use one declaration `var` or `let` or `const` in a statement, **even normally, outside for-loop**

i.e.

```
var data = [], i = 0;
```

or

```
let data = [], i = 0;
```

Which is why your second snippet makes more sense

```
let data = []; //make it var if it needs a function-wide scope
for (let i=0; i<1000; ++i) {
    // Do something here that populates the data variable.
}
```

if `data` is declared as `let` in for-loop inline, then `data` will not be accessible outside

```
for (let data = [], i=0; i<1000; ++i) {
    // Do something here that populates the data variable.
}
console.log(data); //Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should declare the other variable outside the loop – and not with `var`, either:

```js
let data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    data.push(i);
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: @messerbill: It uses `let data`, not `var data`

Comment: oh sorry true that

Comment: why not with `var`? You can't really make that decision. It's perfectly possible that the OP wanted and needed a `var` scope.

Comment: @Liam: `var` scope is literally never\* necessary

Comment: @Ryan except in the global scope

Comment: @Bergi: True! I have added an asterisk.

Comment: @Ryan So never say never, but say never* instead? :-D

Comment: If you're in the global scope - do you need var at all?

Comment: @Richard: If you’re in strict mode, yep.